# Creating Custom Commands

Tags: 18.04, bash

I am creating bash scripts and placing them in bin to be executed as commands. I have had no problems until my most recent command. I am attempting to create a command to restart network-manager.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service network-manager restart
```

this runs fine is run as the root user. If I run it as a non-root sudoer, the command prompts for a password and then fails with the following response (the command i made is called resnet):

```
user2@pavilion: resnet
Failed to restart natwork-manager.service: Unit natwork-manager.service not found.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The error doesn't match the text in the script. Does the script saved in the `bin` directory contain the exact command `sudo service network-manager restart`? Or does it have `network-manager` misspelled as `natwork-manager`, as in the message? I suspect that the file that root is running when you run `sudo resnet` (if that's how you're doing it) is different from the file your user runs when you run `resnet`, which is expected when your `$PATH` is not the same as `secure_path` in the sudoers file. This is all a guess though, and not even a specific one. Please **[edit]** with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo in service name "natwork-manager" instead of "network-manager"

```
 Unit natwork-manager.service not found
```

Comment: This doesn't quite explain why running the script as root works but running it as a non-root user does not. Still, this is likely the best answer that can be given until the OP [provides more information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161766/creating-custom-commands#comment1935516_1161766).